# Perl LibXML adding nodes in a loop

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I'm trying to add nodes from one document to a new document I create, but it's not working and I don't know why. Here's the code that's going wrong:

```
my ($body_node) = $newdoc->findnodes('//body');
    my @nodes = $source_doc->findnodes('//div[starts-with(@psname, "xyz")]');
    foreach my $node(@nodes) {
        $body_node = $body_node->appendChild($node);
    }
$newdoc->toFile($outfile);
```

The code looks for some named div tags and appends them to the body tag. The problem is that it's appending them to the last div tag, not to the body tag so I'm ending up with a bunch of nested divs:

```
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div> 
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 0):

That means you probably need to come back to `<body>` after adding `<div>`:

```
my ($body_node) = $newdoc->findnodes('//body');
my @nodes = $source_doc->findnodes('//div[starts-with(@psname, "xyz")]');
foreach my $node(@nodes) {
    $body_node = $body_node->appendChild($node);
    ($body_node) = $newdoc->findnodes('//body');
}
open (OUT, ">$outfile");
print OUT $newdoc->toString();
close OUT;
```

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work. I also tried with $body_node = $body_node->appendChild($node); but again didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Your code only added two nodes to newdoc. There are about 30 nodes in the source document that I should be matching on.

Comment: and if you loop on `$newdoc->findnodes('//body')[0]->appendChild($node);` any better ?

Comment: That actually gives me a syntax error. I removed [0] and then I get the error "Can't locate object method "appendChild" via package ..."

Comment: yes i should have added extra ()  to encapsulate the method call before the [0]. but that wouldn't have worked better than my original reply. did you try also to loop on `$body_node->addSibling($node);` ?

Comment: Your first suggestion of adding ($body_node) = $newdoc->findnodes('//body'); to the loop is actually producing some good results if I convert the resulting $newdoc to a string and then save the string to file. In other words, not using $newdoc->toFile($outfile) fixes the problem. Thanks for your help, much appeciated.

Comment: Edited my reply in case somebody needs it in the future.

Comment: You need to change the first line in the loop to $body_node = $body_node->appendChild($node); Thanks.